# Using Unity without Prism

Tags: unity-container

Im starting learning Silverlight (Im decent with WPF :P). Im always try to put something new when I start a new program. This time I want DI. I saw all the mtaulty videos about Prism & Silverlight but the regions thing, all that projects, when to use SL app or SL library, catalog... Seems difficult to me right now.

The thing is, I want to use Unity on a MVVM Light project. My question is simple:

How I register all my services? I mean "Where".

On Prism in every project with services you have an IModule implementation where register your services.

I just want a single project solution for ease.

Should I register all my services (including repositories) on App.xaml.cs?, Should I create some kind of class for Unity sake? or Should I be a man an read the entire prism4.pdf and do the things correctly? (Prism4.pdf seems to be a little unfriendly :P)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, Unity and Prism don't need each other to work. Unity works perfectly fine without using Prism.
With Unity, you have to register your interfaces (services) in a config file, and load this config at the start of your program (App.xaml.cs is not a bad place). It is also possible to register the services using code, but this makes it more difficult to swap out dummy interfaces with real implementations for example. From here on you can use `unityContainer.Resolve<T>` to retrieve your services and interfaces.

Comment: Good answer. how difficult? I mean, if I have a config file (I have to search how to implement it) with my services registered or I have my services registered in code. I have to change my dummy implementations with real ones changing the config file or the code. Same trouble, isn't it?

Comment: yes but changing the config file doesn't require a rebuild of your code, so it makes it easier to swap out components.

Comment: Be aware that if you're writing a Silverlight app, you can't use a config file since there's no config system there. You'll need to use the API. I generally extract the registration code into a separate class, and then apply the registrations when the app starts up.

Comment: @Chris, didn't saw your comment... You mean that I have to create a class that register all the modules and instantiate it on the app.xaml.cs?

Comment: Something along those lines, yes. Basically, you need code that calls the Unity API to configure the container. I personally prefer to have that code in a separate class.